# Javascript Regex Function "test" is working in internal js But not working in the External js File

Tags: javascript

[image]I am testing the email validation on "ahmadzia307@gmail.com".
When I test the email through REGEX method 'TEST', it is working in internal js. But when I move the validation code to the External js file. It does not validate the same email correctly.

```
function validateEmail2(email) {

    var filters = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filters.test(email))
        return false
    return true
}
```

Comment: how you're moving it to external file ? show that code too

Comment: I have added the picture of code. For external I just copy the Method to external js and Add '2' to the method name. to test both methods

Comment: You need to export function from `external` and also import where you want to use,

Comment: I have imported external file in the view. And the method of email validation is copied in the external as this  function validateEmail2(email) above shown

Comment: I hope that you are using that regex for some pre-validation of the email addresses. That regex does not guarantee if a given email address is valid. If it is not for a personal project, please add another validation: send a confirmation mail instead to verify if the given email is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your regex is nit valid, try the below,

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/


function validateEmail2(email) {

    var filters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

    if (!filters.test(email))
        return false
    return true
}
```

Source - https://emailregex.com/

Refer the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: But it is working on the same email when i write and use the js methods internally. I will try your answer.

Comment: yes, please try. refer the screenshot i think your regex has some issues

Comment: :) thanks dont forget to make as correct answer :D ;)

Comment: It might be because of 2 `@` in the regex. Regex in the question looks faulty to me too.

Comment: I remove the 1 @ from the expression, it is working. @Code_Ninja

Comment: Thumbs up @Code_Ninja and Muhammad